# Discriminant of an quaternion algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, discriminant

Given an quaternion algebra $\mathcal{A} = (\alpha, \beta)_\mathbb{K}$ it is known that the $$\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A}) = \prod \mbox{ideal primes where $\mathcal{A}$ is ramified}.$$

Ok, but I really don't know *how* to compute this. How do I find these prime ideals?

Comment: Are you working with global fields?  If so, you can reduce the problem to local fields.

Comment: yes, I am working with a number field. How can I reduce this problem? For example, if I have $\mathcal{A} = (\sqrt{2},-1)_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2)}$, how to compute the discriminant using local fields?

Comment: See any text on quaternion algebras (vigneras, peirce's book on associative algebras, john voight's book, my notes, ....) or you can do it in magma.  You don't need to find prime ideals, just compute local Hilbert symbols.